# OWL CAROUSEL : image height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello StackOverflow community.

In my new Java EE project I decided to use Owl Carousel, a powerful, flexible, and easy to use plugin to display some available gifts to win.

I noticed some unwanted behaviour regarding the customization of the images height.

**Here is an image of the page using owl carousel but without customization of the height of images :** 
[image]

**Here is an image of the page using owl carousel with customization of the height of images :**

[image]

**here is the code i'm using ti generate the carousel :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var owl = $("#owl-demo");

  owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 6, //10 items above 1000px browser width
    itemsDesktop: [1199, 4], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3], // betweem 900px and 601px
    itemsTablet: [600, 2], //2 items between 600 and 0
    itemsMobile: [479, 1] // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
  });

  // Custom Navigation Events
  $(".next").click(function() {
    owl.trigger('owl.next');
  })
  $(".prev").click(function() {
    owl.trigger('owl.prev');
  })
  $(".play").click(function() {
    owl.trigger('owl.play', 1000); //owl.play event accept autoPlay speed as second parameter
  })
  $(".stop").click(function() {
    owl.trigger('owl.stop');
  })

});
```

```css
.img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  /* the problem (if you remove it, the carousel works !!!! )*/
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#owl-demo .item {
  color: #FFF;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid rgb(228, 228, 228);
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #93C572;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <h4 style="text-align: center;">Cadeaux À Votre Portée</h4>
  <div class="customNavigation">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500" style="margin-right: 20px;" /><a class="btn prev">&lt;</a>  <a class="btn next">&gt;</a> 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500" style="margin-left: 20px;" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <p:panel styleClass="item">
      <div class="row">
        <p:graphicImage styleClass="img" library="espace" name="http://placehold.it/500" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">1700 PTs</div>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="item">
      <div class="row">
        <p:graphicImage styleClass="img" library="espace" name="http://placehold.it/500" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">1250 PTs</div>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="item">
      <div class="row">
        <p:graphicImage styleClass="img" library="espace" name="http://placehold.it/500" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">900 PTs</div>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="item">
      <div class="row">
        <p:graphicImage styleClass="img" library="espace" name="http://placehold.it/500" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">1300 PTs</div>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="item">
      <div class="row">
        <p:graphicImage styleClass="img" library="espace" name="http://placehold.it/500" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">3000 PTs</div>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="item">
      <div class="row">
        <p:graphicImage styleClass="img" library="espace" name="http://placehold.it/500" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">1500 PTs</div>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="item">
      <div class="row">
        <p:graphicImage styleClass="img" library="espace" name="http://placehold.it/500" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">900 PTs</div>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="item">
      <div class="row">
        <p:graphicImage styleClass="img" library="espace" name="http://placehold.it/500" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">1300 PTs</div>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="item">
      <div class="row">
        <p:graphicImage styleClass="img" library="espace" name="http://placehold.it/500" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">1300 PTs</div>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="item">
      <div class="row">
        <p:graphicImage styleClass="img" library="espace" name="http://placehold.it/500" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">1300 PTs</div>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="item">
      <div class="row">
        <p:graphicImage styleClass="img" library="espace" name="http://placehold.it/500" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-shopping-cart" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">1300 PTs</div>
    </p:panel>


  </div>
</div>
```

**---EDITED---**

May be I wasn't very clear about what is the problem :

- If I don't edit the height of the images inside the carousel it works
  fine like in the first image. (CSS is in a separate file)
- If I try to edit the height of the images inside the carousel the page
  becomes blank like in the second image. (CSS is in a separate file)

I'm not very familiar with jQuery and JavaScript so I don't understand what is the reason of this behaviour.

**----EDITED 2----**

THIS PROBLEM IS PRESENT ONLY IN **GOOGLE CHROME**, NOT IN **INTERNET EXPLORER** AND NOT IN **MOZILLA FIREFOX**.

Comment: it's unclear of what is the unwanted behavior

Comment: You could place a class on each image and force them to be the height you want them to be.

Comment: **@Andrew**: i have already done that !!! check the code snippet there is a class named (.img), **@Jossef Harush** the unwanted behavior is that the hole page became blank (compare the images i have posted !!!!!!)

Comment: would be helpful if you provide the rendered HTML. That way things can be put down together to view the end result. May be you can set it up in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Lokesh Yadav here is the code you wanted http://jsfiddle.net/cs69odxy/  but the problem is not shown in that simulator !!! hope it helps .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by just updating the height of the images from **130px** to **135px**, i just found this solution randomly but still i don't understand the reason behind the problem or the solution.

**Old CSS code :**

```
.img {  display: inline-block;  max-width: 100%;  height: 130px;    margin-bottom: 30px; }
```

**New CSS code :**

```
.img {  display: inline-block;  max-width: 100%;  height: *135px*;  margin-bottom: 30px;}
```